# dgrid pagination example

Tags: dojo, pagination, dgrid

Can anyone point me to an example of using the Pagination extension of dgrid with a dgrid? This could be a reference link or a simple example you type up. I've defined it in my code, used it with an OnDemandGrid where it is added to the declare mixin for my custom grid. I see arrows for page navigation, I see the page size setting menu, but my specification of rowsPerPage: 3 does nothing. I still see my 7 sample records.

I'm using a modified Cache (data object store) that wraps a JsonRest and Memory store for my dgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you can't use `OnDemandGrid` with pagination since the `OnDemandGrid` has it's own internal virtual paging logic.  From the [dgrid extensions wiki](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Extensions):

> In contrast to the OnDemandList and OnDemandGrid modules, the
>   Pagination extension implements classic discrete paging controls. It
>   displays a certain number of results at a given time, and provides a
>   footer area with controls to switch between pages.
>
> **Note: the Pagination extension should be mixed into List or Grid, not
>   one of the OnDemand constructors, since those contain their own
>   virtual scrolling logic**. Internally, Pagination inherits from the same
>   _StoreMixin module inherited by the OnDemand prototypes for common integration with dojo/store.

What you want to do instead is mixin `Pagination` into a plain `Grid`.  The Pagination Mixin includes the properties you're interested in such as number of rows.  The Paginator extension handles talking to the provided store  for retrieving and rendering the set of rows to display.  A `define` for a class like that might look like:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare','dgrid/Grid', 'dgrid/extensions/Pagination'],function(declare,Grid,Pagination){
    return declare('mine.PaginatedGrid',[Grid,Pagination],{
      //various default you can set
      pagingLinks: false,
      pagingTextBox: true,
      firstLastArrows: true,
      minRowsPerPage: 5,
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100]
    });
});
```

Comment: For me that is not a clear description. Is it saying not to use Pagination extension for OnDemandGrid (ODG) but do use it when using List or Grid? It seems to, so then how does it show how many results there are and how does the ODG interact with a Cache store that wraps JsonRest and Memory stores? Do I still include Pagination in the Define for the ODG? Is the row count shown based on the portal size or can it be specified? i.e. if I want 5 records to show at a time, how to I specify that?

Comment: edited my answer to hopefully clarify how to use extensions/Pagination with Grid.

Comment: Thanks BuffaloBuffalo.
What would I be giving up if I use a Grid instead of an OnDemandGrid?

Comment: I found the docs for OnDemandGrid in the dgrid docs. It apparently is the lazy-load of data on demand vs a more manually controlled approach using Pagination model.

Answer (score 0):

The best examples of DGrid and its extensions can be found in the test folder of the DGrid project.  They can be found here:

- [DGrid Tests](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/tree/master/test)

Specifically the Paginations Tests can be found:

- [Here,](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/extensions/Pagination.html)
- [here,](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/extensions/Pagination_i18n.html)
- [and here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/extensions/Pagination_tree.html)

To run them:

1. Clone the git repo
2. Drop it on your webserver
3. Navigate to the html page